# selenium web test transition to java applet test and back

Tags: selenium, web, applet

I have an automated web test written using selenium web driver, and it works great for the web portion of my test.  But part of the test from the web page actually runs a local java applet (downloaded if not there) that performs a function and then auto-closes when finished.  I'd like the selenium test to seamlessly transfer to an automated test I could run on the java applet and then continue once the automated test part on the java applet is complete.  Any suggestions on how to go about this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add in a Swing testing library such as [FEST](http://code.google.com/p/fest/) and proceed with the applet testing. Once the applet section is done, you could come back to Selenium for your web portion.

As far as I know, you could not do the applet testing using Selenium.

Edit : Looks like Googling "swing gui testing" gives you few other options.